# How can I prevent autosubmitting in FormPage?

Tags: cloud-deploy

If I deploy this code:

```
CloudDeploy[FormPage[{"x" -> <|"Input" -> "Apple"|>}, Identity]]
```

When I execute the URL the form is automaticaly submitted as in the image below

[image: form image]

To prevend auto submitting, as mentioned in [this post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/898662), I tried:

```
CloudDeploy[FormPage[{"x" -> <|"Input" -> "Apple", "AutoSubmitting" -> False|>}, Identity]]
```

...but without success. Any clue?

The real case is a form with some default values that can be changed before the submition.

Comment: Adding `HoldForm` suppresses the automatic submission but keeps the default input: `CloudDeploy[FormPage[{"x" -> <|"Input" -> HoldForm["Apple"]|>}, Identity]]`

Answer (score 1):

Using @rowsi's hint, in my real world case "Apple" is a variable, so we need `Evaluate` to solve It:

```
myVar = "Apple";
CloudDeploy@FormPage[
      {"x" -> <|"Input" -> HoldForm@Evaluate[myVar]|>}
      , Identity
  ]
```